# Getting Permission Error to get output in a folder when running a cuda based jupyter notebook in vs code on my Desktop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, permission-denied

I am running a cuda based jupyter notebook in vs code on my Desktop. The training has just         started for epoch:0 and iteration:0 but it is not moving further according to train.log but code cell in jupyter notebook is running continuously without showing any error. I am not getting/saving any intermediate state(every 1000th) which is to be saved in a particular folder.
When I re-run the code cell following error is coming:

```
 `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
Path already exists. Rename it to     [C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/Sobel/code/root_release\experiments\SPSR_1_archived_230606-104843]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samsung\Desktop\Sobel\code\train.py", line 191, in <module>
    main()
   File "C:\Users\samsung\Desktop\Sobel\code\train.py", line 33, in main
    util.mkdir_and_rename(opt['path']['experiments_root'])  # rename old folder if exists
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\samsung\Desktop\Sobel\code\utils\util.py", line 41, in mkdir_and_rename
    os.rename(path, new_name)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:   'C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/Sobel/code/root_release\\experiments\\SPSR_1' ->   'C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/Sobel/code/root_release\\experiments\\SPSR_1_archived_230606-104843'
```

I have tried to change permission settings for the particular folder. But settings are already as required as shown in picture below:
[Properties window for the folder where output is expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okiHe.png)``

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by simply changing the drive(C: to D:) of complete folder containing the code and other files.
D: drive has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).